Is it possible to have a single IP for a VM in different networks?
I am learning about DNS administration in Linux. And I do it in my office and home. In office my IP range is 10.x.x.x/21 whereas in my home, my IP range is 192.x.x.x/24. Since I am learning DNS by implementing BIND DNS, I need static IP. But the issue is that, say I configured my static IP in office, now I can do everything in it in office(connect to internet, SSH to it etc), but when I come home, I am unable to ssh it, I am unable to connect to internet. Is there a good way? I am using virtualbox for virtualization.

AFAIK, the only way to do so would be to change the DNS IP Subnet of your home router to 10.x.x.x/21, ensuring the IP Subnet block chosen includes the IP the device is assigned at the office

@JW0914 : That is an alternative to the approach I discuss in my answer.  But, ugh...  then the home network would be using 10.x.x.x/21, and potentially conflict with the office network?  That doesn't sound quite so good.  On the other hand, if the home network used non-conflicting addresses in the 10.x.x.x/20 range, then that could potentially work.  (Different devices on a network can have different prefixes/subnet-masks, and that can work just fine.  Or be quite problematic, depending on whether a person truely understands what they are doing.  Not something I usually prefer, but can work.)

It might also help to understand that people consider an IP address to have two parts.  The first part, the "subnet portion", uses bits at the start of the address identifies which subnet you're on.  The second part, the "host ID portion", uses the remaining bits (at the end of the address) identifies which device (on the subnet) you're using.  So having a single address on two different subnets breaks the intended design, and is not generally desirable, as the subnet portion's SHOULDn't match, by design.    (One could use NAT to have one address communicate with differnet subnets.)

This looks to me like a classic case of the XY Problem, asked by someone rather new to networking.
What I think you may actually want is to have a machine (whether it is a virtual machine, or a physical mobile machine, doesn't really matter) which can communicate on two networks.
The easy way to do that is going to be to assign two different IP addresses to the same machine (and, more specifically, possibly to the same network card/port/interface).
Bridging is quite unrelated to IP, actually.  A true "bridge" receives "OSI Layer 2" traffic, that is data "frames" delivered using a MAC-48 address, and sending the frame out another port.  Therefore, the Layer 2 traffic on one frame gets to another network.
On the other hand, IP addressing relates to "OSI Layer 3", and is designed for routing.  The idea of routing is that neighbor discovery (called ND in IPv6, and ARP is the common equivalent in IPv4) matches a Layer 3 (IP) address to a Layer 2 (MAC-48) address, and then sends the Layer 3 packet in a layer 2 frame to the desired layer 2 address.  If ND cannot find an address for the destination IP, then the sending machine does neighbor discovery for a "gateway IP" address, and sends traffic there instead.
So if you want to send traffic to a /24 inside 192.0.0.0/8 (if you're using classic IPv4 addresses, that will more-specifically be within the 192.168.0.0/16 subnet), then you'll either need to have an address in that subnet (the easy way), or traffic would need to get routed/translated to deal with the address that is not part of the same 192.168.0.0/24 subnet.  That may mean implementing NAT and/or adjusting routing tables on a router that has an address in the same (192.168.0.0/24) subnet.  That may be able to be done, but is NOT the easy way!
Just assign both IP addresses to one machine.  (Most popular TCP/IP implementations will support being able to do this on a single interface.)
Then when you try to reach an "office" address in the 10.0.0.0/8 range, the local machine's routing table can direct such traffic out your network interface.  When you try to reach a "home network" address in the 192.168.0.0/24 range, the local machine's routing table can direct such traffic out your network interface.  Both of those scenarios can use the same physical network interface.  Not only will that work fine, but if you do that, then other machines will see an internal/recognized in-the-same-subnet address, and will be able to easily reply.
Replies, by the way, are often more important than you may think.  For instance, if you send ICMP traffic (e.g. ping), you may be able to send even if a reply doesn't successfully send back to you.  But if you are trying to use TCP (e.g., HTTP and SMTP, including HTTPS and SMTPS variations, use TCP, as do very numerous other protocols), then a reply is required to complete TCP's 3-way handshake before a single bit of "payload" data can be sent using the TCP protocol.
Regarding the Virtualbox setup you describe, you may wish to hvae the Virtual box machine's [virtual] network adapter [virtual] hardware communicate over a software bridge to one of your physical machine's network interfaces.  (That is one way to do things, and has some advantages and disadvantages to alternative possible ways to set things up.)  If you want to be able to SSH into your Virtual Box machine, then you'll be wanting your Virtual Box machine's interface to have an IP address assigned in both subnets (in order to implemenet the basic advice of this answer).
Alternative: You might just wish to set up your Virtual Box machine to use DHCP, and then somehow (maybe manually) renew the lease each time you switch networks.  You can get a consistent IP address on the 192.168.0.0/24 network if you have a "reserved address" reserved by the DHCP server.  (That requires control of the DHCP server that handles the 192.168.0.0/24 network, or cooperation by whomever does control that, in order to set up the DHCP reservation).  Likewise, you could have  a reservation on the network within the 10.0.0.0/8 addresses if you can manage to get the DHCP server there to have a reservation for your MAC-48 address.  That is certainly technically possible, but, just as a warning, many system administrators may think it to be rather unnecessary and therefore elect to not set up such a reservation on your behalf.  So, that might commonly be less feasible, especially for an office network.

Since I am learning DNS by implementing BIND DNS, I need static IP.

Probably not.  First of all, the term "static IP" does get used different ways.  I was classically trained that "static IP" refers to manually-assigned addresses that don't use any sort of automatic address assignment protocol.  Some people consider a "reserved address" to also be a static IP.
Regardless, another alternative may be to use DDNS (which may potentially involve automatic updates of BIND data).  That might, or might not, make much sense for your particular scenario of dealing with addresses on an end-user workstation.  But even if it doesn't, DDNS can be useful in other scenarios where BIND may get used, so don't think that BIND can only ever be used with static IP addresses.
